# parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 4

Tags: json, parsing, jq

I am trying to parse a json using `jq` but it is giving parse error, I believe my Json is valid.

```
 echo {"ok":true,"elapsed":"317ns"} | jq -r '.ok'
jq: parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 3
```

Can you please help?

I tried putting ' around the query, then it works fine, but I am not able to understand what's issue with first one.

```
echo '{"ok":true,"elapsed":"317ns"}' | jq -r '.ok'
true
```

Comment: How is this problem related to programming? What makes you think that the first command should work?

Comment: In the unquoted case, special characters like `{` or `"` will be interpreted by the shell you are running this in. The shell's evaluation of the arguments (just `ok:true elapsed:317ns` in this case) is then passed on to `echo` to be printed to `stdout`, which is then picked up from `stdin` by `jq`, which will rightly complain as this is not JSON anymore. With the quotes, the entire content between them is sent unaltered down the same stream, reaching `jq`, which can process it as it is still JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's look at what the shell does with that echo statement:

```bash
$ echo {"ok":true,"elapsed":"317ns"}
ok:true elapsed:317ns
```

Several things happened:

- the braces disappeared,
- the comma disappeared,
- the quotes disappeared.

Assuming your shell is bash, this is explained in [3.5.1 Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) and [3.5.9 Quote Removal](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quote-Removal)

Shells are tricky languages. This is why it's important to use quotes everywhere.

```bash
echo '{"ok":true,"elapsed":"317ns"}' | jq -r '.ok'
# ...^.............................^
```

Or, if your JSON data is stored in a variable:

```bash
json='{"ok":true,"elapsed":"317ns"}'
echo "$json" | jq -r '.ok'
# ...^.....^
```